# how to sum the digits in an integer using recusion?

Tags: recursion

Write a recursive method that computes the sum of the sum of the digits in an integer. use the following method header:

public static int sumDigits(long n)

For example, sumDigits(234) returns 2 + 3 + 4 = 9. Write a real program that prompts the user to enter an integer and displays its sum.

Comment: Are you asking for help on a hw assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Receive an integer as a parameter

Convert to string

Parse the string's individual characters

Remove a character (first or last doesn't matter)

Put the remaining characters back into a single string

Cast that string back to integer

Call "result = removedChar As Integer + function(remainingChars as Integer)"  <--- this is the recursion

In the future you should at least make one attempt for others to help you edit when you post an obvious homework question ;)

Comment: Did you see the header of the method that is called recursively? You shouldn't use strings but a number...

Comment: @csabinho Did you see that the function called recursively takes an integer as the parameter?  The way you "peel" a single digit out of a numeric value is to convert to string, remove character, cast back to number...I intentionally did not add explicit Code because this is clearly a homework problem.  I simply provided some logic to get OP started.

Comment: No, it's much easier. With `n%10` you'll get the last digit. Don't use strings for such functions.

Comment: @csabinho Ok, that gives you the last digit.  How do you get the new integer without that last digit to pass to your recursive function?  Also feel free to give an example answer that doesn't use strings.  The problem doesn't have only one solution.

Comment: `n/10` gives you the next step. That's what recursion is all about. But with those two informations I almost feel like I've given too much information for a homework.

Comment: And of course your solution is valid as well, but you shouldn't use it unless you want to burn loads of processing time.